# Postgres: Optimize a huge GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query-optimization, aggregation

I have such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE values (first_id varchar(26), sec_id int, mode varchar(6), external1_id varchar(23), external2_id varchar(26), x int, y int);
```

There may be multiple values having the same first_id, my goal is to flatten (into json) for each first_id, all the related rows, into another table.

I do this this way:

```
INSERT INTO othervalues(first_id, results)
  SELECT first_id, json_agg(values) AS results FROM values GROUP BY first_id;
```

In the results column, I have a json array of all the rows, that I can use later as it is.

My problem is that this is very slow, with a huge table: with about 100 000 000 rows in values, this slows down my computer (I actually test locally) until it dies (this is an Ubuntu).

Using EXPLAIN I noticed that is used a GroupPartitioner, I added:

```
SET work_mem = '1GB';
```

Now it uses a HashPartitioner, but this still kills my computer. An explain gives me:

```
Insert on othervalues  (cost=2537311.89..2537316.89 rows=200 width=64)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=2537311.89..2537316.89 rows=200 width=64)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2537311.89..2537314.39 rows=200 width=206)
              ->  Seq Scan on values  (cost=0.00..2251654.26 rows=57131526 width=206)
```

Any idea how to optimize it?

Comment: Wait... `values` is both the name of a column _and_ of a table?  Is there a typo in your insert query?

Comment: Do you have an index on `first_id`?

Comment: @stickybit An index likely would not help much with the call to `json_agg`, which would probably have to touch every value in the group (read: scan).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Ah missed, that `values` isn't a column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is a whole-row reference.

Comment: Can you explain "dies" and "kills" in this context? What exactly happens?

Comment: Sorry for the "values" I renamed my real table. My computer dies means it freezes, after one hour with a request I can't even move the mouse. I didn't mention it but my postgres is dockerized.

Comment: With Postgres 11 partitioning of the table might be an option as that can evaluate aggregates on partitions in parallel. If there aren't too many distinct `first_id` values ("hundreds", but not "thousands") list partitioning on that column might help. Or maybe hash partitioning on it if there are many (maybe even unknown) values

Answer (score 0):

The solution I finally use is to split the GROUP BY into multiple:

First I create a temporary table with the unique IDs of the stuff I want to group. This allow to get only a part of the results - like with OFFSET and LIMIT - but these there can be very slow with huge results sets (big offset mean the execution tree will yet browse the first results):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tempids AS SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY theid), theid FROM (SELECT DISTINCT theid FROM sourcetable) sourcetable;
```

Then in a WHILE loop:

```
DO $$DECLARE
  r record;
  i INTEGER := 0;
  step INTEGER := 500000;
  size INTEGER := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempids);
  BEGIN
  WHILE i <= size
      LOOP
        INSERT INTO target(theid, theresult)
        SELECT ... 
        WHERE tempids > i AND tempids < i + step
       GROUP BY tempids.theid;
```

This looks like usual coding, this is not nice sql, but this works.